# BLE - How to get response after writing command?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I have a BLE device with a "particular protocol".

I need to send a command to retrieve heart rate measurements (using notifications).

My question is: how can I get response after write the "send command"?

**MY STEPS:**

1) Check if the BLE is supported on the device

2) Enable Bluetooth

3) Start the scan of the devices

4) if I find my device (a smartwatch) then I connect to it

5) Once I'm connected, I start the "discover services"

6) In `onServicesDiscovered()` what do I have to do?

I have to write (send command) before call `setCharacteristicNotification()` or viceversa?

Comment: if you get any answer, let me know.....